# how to create sub dictionaries of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch

I have following ddictionary in pytorch

```
OrderedDict([('first', tensor([[[ 0.4713, -0.6487]],
    [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],
    [[ 0.6851,  0.2049]],
    [[-0.3450,  0.5549]],
    [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],
    [[-0.3450,  0.5549]]]))
```

I want to create this into two or multiple dictionaries. how can i do this ?

```
dictionary 1 = [ 0.4713, -0.6487]], [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],[[ 0.6851, 
 0.2049]]

dictionary 2 =   [[-0.3450,  0.5549]], [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],
[[-0.3450,  0.5549]]
```

I tried this imple code but dont know how to do this one with tensor

```
import numpy as np

dic = {
  "A": [0.2822, -0.0958, -0.5165, -0.3812,
        -0.3469,  0.4025, -0.0696, -0.1246,
        -0.1132,  0.4170, -0.0383, -0.4071,
        -0.5407,  0.1519,  0.5630,  0.1276],
  "B": [1.0014, 0.9980, 1.0012, 0.9986,
       1.0001, 0.9999, 1.0016, 1.0014,
       1.0008, 0.9996, 1.0008, 1.0004,
       1.0000, 0.9987, 0.9997, 0.9989]
}

# We give array_split() our list, and how many we want it split into.
a1, a2 = np.array_split(dic['A'], 2) # We get our two lists returned.
dic['A1'] = a1.tolist() # Numpy returns it as an np.array, so let's put it back into a list.
dic['A2'] = a2.tolist()
del(dic['A']) # Remove the now unused key-value.
```

Comment: What is the criteria to be used to split the dictionary?

Comment: if we have parent dictionary of  size 12 ,, we can create 2sub dictionaries of size 6

Comment: You don't have a dictionary of size 6.  You have a list inside an OrderedDictionary of len = 1, which contains a tuple where the second element of the tuple is a tensorObject of len 6

Comment: ok got it.. and what if we want to divde it into 2 chunks

Comment: like i mentioned in question chunk 1 = [ 0.4713, -0.6487]], [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],[[ 0.6851, 
 0.2049]]

chunk 2 =   [[-0.3450,  0.5549]], [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],
[[-0.3450,  0.5549]]

Comment: splitting a python list of lists is different from splitting a numpy array, which do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code doesn't seem to have any bearing on your question, I am not quite sure what you are trying to do.  I see two possibilities: (1) you have a list of lists as illustrated by the variable a below, or (2) you have an np array as illustrated by the variable npa below.  Thus there are two approaches to produce your desired results as demonstrated in the following:

```
import numpy as np
# a list of lists
a = a = [[[ 0.4713, -0.6487]],
    [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],
    [[ 0.6851,  0.2049]],
    [[-0.3450,  0.5549]],
    [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],
    [[-0.3450,  0.5549]]]  

# an np array
npa = array([[[ 0.4713, -0.6487]],

       [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],

       [[ 0.6851,  0.2049]],

       [[-0.345 ,  0.5549]],

       [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],

       [[-0.345 ,  0.5549]]])
```

To create the dictionary using a:

```
{1: inLst[:len(a)//2], 2: inLst[len(a)//2:]}
```

this yields:

```
{1: [[[0.4713, -0.6487]], [[-0.2126, 0.0831]], [[0.6851, 0.2049]]],
 2: [[[-0.345, 0.5549]], [[-0.5363, 0.3424]], [[-0.345, 0.5549]]]}
```

To create the dictionary from npa:

```
a1, a2 =  np.array_split(npar, 2)
{1: a1, 2: a2}
```

this yields:

```
{1: array([[[ 0.4713, -0.6487]],
 
        [[-0.2126,  0.0831]],
 
        [[ 0.6851,  0.2049]]]),
 2: array([[[-0.345 ,  0.5549]],
 
        [[-0.5363,  0.3424]],
 
        [[-0.345 ,  0.5549]]])}
```

Take your pick, based on your exact needs.